# How i can disable link after one click with jQuery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a list of products that i can add in cart, but after its add i would like to disable the link for prevent to add twice the same product

i tried jquery function but the only thing i've been able to do its disabled all my add links or its didn't work at all
my add link is in the loop but i dont want disable all link in same time

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Isbn
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Auteur
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Titre
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Prix
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Photo
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="AcheterLivre" asp-Controller="Achat" asp-route-id="@item.Isbn" class="disabled"> Ajouter <img src="~/images/panier.png" /></a>
                </td>
                <td><a href="~/resume/resume.txt" target="_blank">Afficher</a></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    }
@section Scripts {
    function fctDesactive(oEvent){
    var bDisabled = this.dataset.disabled == 'true';
    if(bDisabled){
    oEvent.preventDefault();
    }else{
    this.dataset.disabled = 'true'
    }
    }

}
```

I would like to understand how i could disabled link once is clicked without disable all my other link

thank you

Comment: Please include your jQuery code.

Comment: i edited my post ;)

Comment: Where do you attach `function fctDesactive` to your anchor link click event?

Comment: You actually don't need jquery or javascript logic to do that. The items array you have from your controller, you can check if the same element exists in your card collection. If so, just set "disabled" attribute on the html tag for that item.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with card collection can you explain me please